# chainerの画像認識 Classifier.predictorの値とは

Tags: python, chainer

Chainerを使ってひらがな73文字を畳み込みニューラルネットワークで画像から学習させ、モデルを保存しました。その学習させたモデルをserializers.load_npzで読み込み、手書き画像を入力し認識させ、上位5個を割合と一緒に結果として表示させるコードを書いています。

目標としている表示結果（例）

```
tegaki_na.pngの識別結果
　な：60%
　た：25%
　は：10%
　あ：4%
　を：1%
```

しかし、その割合として利用しようとしていたpredictorのdataから得られる行列（要素73個）は正の値から負の値まであるため、そのまま割合としては使えないことがわかりました（すべてを足しても1や100になることはありませんでした）。
公式のChainer.Links.Classifierの項目を読んでもpredictorの出力の形までは説明が書いておらず、手詰まりになっためここで質問させていただきました。

以下ソースコードです。ここではpredictorの中の実際の値をそのまま出力するようになっています（これをパーセントにしたい）

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import chainer
import chainer.links as L
from chainer import Variable
#畳み込みのモデルはconvolution_model.pyとして保存してある
import convolution_model as CNN

label = ['あ', 'い', 'う', 'え', 'お',
         'か', 'が', 'き', 'ぎ', 'く', 'ぐ', 'け', 'げ', 'こ', 'ご',
         'さ', 'ざ', 'し', 'じ', 'す', 'ず', 'せ', 'ぜ', 'そ', 'ぞ',
         'た', 'だ', 'ち', 'ぢ', 'つ', 'づ', 'て', 'で', 'と', 'ど',
         'な', 'に', 'ぬ', 'ね', 'の',
         'は', 'ば', 'ぱ', 'ひ', 'び', 'ぴ', 'ふ', 'ぶ', 'ぷ', 'へ', 'べ', 'ぺ', 'ほ', 'ぼ', 'ぽ',
         'ま', 'み', 'む', 'め', 'も',
         'や', 'ゆ', 'よ',
         'ら', 'り', 'る', 'れ', 'ろ', 'わ', 'ゐ', 'ゑ', 'を', 'ん']

#画像サイズは48x48である前提
model = L.Classifier(CNN.Model())
chainer.serializers.load_npz('nihongo.model', model)

def loadimg(image):
    img_ = cv2.imread(image, 0) #グレースケールとして読み込み

    height, width = img_.shape[:2]
    if height!=48 or width!=48: #縦または横の長さが48pxではない場合
        img_ = cv2.resize(img_,(48,48)) #48x48にリサイズ

    img_ = img_.astype(np.float32)/255
    temp=[]
    temp2=[]
    temp.append(img_)
    temp2.append(temp)
    img_ = np.array(temp2)
    return img_

def score(image):
    img = loadimg(image)

    result = model.predictor(Variable(img))
    result = result.data[0] #それぞれの文字である確率？

    a_label = np.argsort(result)
    a_ratio = np.sort(result)

    a_label = a_label[-1::-1]
    a_ratio = a_ratio[-1::-1]
    return a_label, a_ratio
```

実行するときのコード（作業ディレクトリにカレントを移動している前提）

```
IMGName='test_ga.png'
AL,AR = score(IMGName)

print(IMGName,'の結果')
for i in range(73):
    ans_l=AL[i]
    print(str(label[ans_l]),':',str(AR[i]))
```

結果

```
tegaki_na.pngの識別結果
　な：42.3303
　た：30.025
　は：26.0882
　あ：25.0445
　を：19.8176
```

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.chainer.org/en/stable/reference/generated/chainer.links.Classifier.html#chainer-links-classifier
https://github.com/chainer/chainer/blob/v3.1.0/chainer/links/model/classifier.py#L71

`L.Classifier`の初期化子に与えた第1引数が`predictor`属性に格納されますから、質問のソースで言うと`model = L.Classifier(CNN.Model())`の`CNN.Model()`の部分ですね。
`convolution_model.py`の中の`Model`で、あなたが定義した値が出ているだけですよ。

（言葉を換えると、`L.Classifier`はあなたが定義した識別モデルを渡されているだけ、ということです）